# How do I install package on the specific folder for freenas for installing phpmyadmin and mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb, jail-shell

How do I install package on the specific folder for freenas for installing phpmyadmin and mariadb. The part I'm stuck on is putting the right folder into the packages like:
Download the necessary packages [2]:

```
apache24 (in web category)
mariadb55-server (in databases category) -- this is the open source drop-in replacement for mysql
php5 (in languages category) -- this is 5.4
php5-mysql, php5-mysqli, php5-pdo, php5-pdo_mysql (in databases category) -- you can add other php extensions if you'd like
mod_php5 (in web category) -- this is the apache php module
phpmyadmin (in databases category)
```

Here's the link for direction I've been following

http://timtonblog.blogspot.ca/2014/11/installing-mariadb-and-phpmyadmin-in.html

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work … then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the command `pkg install`, for example, to install `MariaDB` you need to do the following:

```
pkg search mariadb
```

> This should get you a list of available packages for MariaDB, next, install the server packages.

```
pkg install mariadb-server
```

> For an specific version:

```
pkg install mariadb-server-5.5.31
```